# Change the default location for "Have Disk" when installing drivers

Tags: windows, windows-7, drivers

When you install a driver for a device and try to install drivers manually from an *.inf file by clicking "Have Disk" - Windows automatically searches `A:`. Which I'm not sure why but takes about 5 seconds before giving a 'select path' dialog box.

Is there a way to change the default search path for a Disk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft articles with the details to specify search locations

None of my windows images look for device location from floppy disk. This may have to with the installation options of your image

Be sure to verify the OS in the articles below.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553973(v=vs.85).aspx

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753716.aspx

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! However, I couldn't find an answer within these articles. They specify where Windows searches for drivers, but not where the `A:\` path is defined (When clicking "Have Disk"). And that is what I'm trying to change

Comment: Windows does not write A:\.  It was either part of the image or the last successful path where the configuration had been obtained previously.  Open regedit and search for A:\ - see how many references you get first.  I have none.  Look at the registry entries described in the article.

Comment: I have one reference to A:\ in the registry, but it doesn't seem related. Anyway - I don't even have a floppy drive! So this path never worked... Also, this is how Windows behaves on my PC and on 2 laptops I've checked. How did you install your images?

Comment: Another idea: use the subst command to point to a location when the A:\ reference is used. Point to the folder you want.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491006.aspx
subst [drive1: [drive2:]Path]
subst drive1 : /d

Comment: That is actually a great idea!! Unfortunately subst fails for `A:` - Meaning there is a `A:` drive. It doesn't show on My Computer, but I had a floppy drive in the device manager which I've now disabled - Now clicking "Have Disk" as described in the question still finding `A:`, but fails immediately - Which is a good workaround for me. Thanks for your help!